# JQuery AJAX Caching with PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm currently trying to speed up the ajax requests made. Basically the site works by live filtering. So when a user clicks on a form element, the data will load accordingly. This all works fantastically well but it's not as quick as I want it to be.

My AJAX looks a bit like this (i've obviously omitted the variables):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'URL NAME',
        data: {
            'Var1': Var1,
            'Var2': Var2
        },
        cache:true, // Set cache to TRUE
        success: function(data) {
            $('.content').html(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#loading_ajax").hide();
            $('.content').fadeIn();
        }   
    }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        $('.content').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
        //alert('[event.status:' + event.status + '], [event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
});
```

On the other side where the data is getting requested, the first lines in the PHP are this:

```
$seconds = 86400;

header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=$seconds");
header("Expires: ".gmdate('r', time()+$seconds));
```

I then went into Firebug to check for caching and it didn't seem to work at all.
Firebug printed out the following:

[image: First Firebug Image]

[image: Second Firebug Image]

[image]

The second screenshot there shows that the request had actually slowed down (I repeated it to see if the caching would improve it and it hasn't made a difference). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: check [something faster then ajax for sending/receiving data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814624/online-gaming-or-something-faster-then-ajax-for-sending-receiving-data/12814665#12814665)

Comment: Could you also post the request headers..

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you control the cache policy from the server configuration, rather than individual files? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html

Comment: @KentPawar - Request headers put in

Comment: BUMP - any ideas? Anyone!?? I know this is a complex issue so I'm kinda expecting not to get a response but I feel a good response would help so many people out there.

Comment: Make sure your headers sent from server arrive to client, for example that they are not overriden later on in your code, or by proxies (if any).

Comment: Hey did you find out why the header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=$seconds") is not getting set? Seems like your host is overriding the settings for security/bandwidth-saving purposes.. http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/

Comment: Hi @KentPawar - I did not find out. I'm going to have a dig on the server I think. Thanks - I'll drop a message back in here when I find out

Comment: Cool. Good luck with that. Generally you could just drop in a mail to the sysadmin support if your site is hosted on a provider

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your website loading time by compressing files into smaller size.

Add this to your .htaccess file

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't make a difference, at all.